# reactjs - how to set style of border?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set a `style` for a component, but I do not know how to write the correct syntax in `React`. My `CSS` looks like this:

```
 .cell {
   border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 }
```

And here is my `render()` method:

```
 render() {
   let styles = {
        ...

       //border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),  <---- Not correct
   };
   return (
     <div className="cell" style={styles}></div>
   );
 }
```

How do I convert the `CSS` syntax into a `React/JS` syntax ?

Comment: you can access this for some reference https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is the thing:

```js
render() {
   const styles = {
        border: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)', 
   };

   return (
     <div style={styles}>Hello</div>
   );
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to write it like inline it must be like this

```
render() {
   return (
     <div style={{border: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)'}} >Hello</div>
   );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

For eg:

```
const divStyle = {
  color: 'blue',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
};
function HelloWorldComponent() {
  return <div style={divStyle}>Hello World!</div>;
```

`border: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)',`

You need declare value in string using `'`to declare a CSS property

Answer (score 0):

Since `styles` is an object, you should write `border: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)'`.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually in camelCase. Example background-color: "white" will be written as backgroundColor: "white"

Answer (score -2):

It is better to keep your css separate from the component itself for readability and debugging sake. Say your component name is `MyComponent.js` on the same level as this file is create a file `MyComponent.module.css` in here place your styles like you would in a normal css file like:

```
 .cell {
   border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 }
```

Then import this in `MyComponent.js` as :

`import styles from ./MyComponent.module.css`

then wherever you need to use it simply do :

```
 <div className={styles.cell}></div>
```

This way your css and js is now separate and you can write your css as you normally would.